# Randomly removing n edges without disconnecting graph

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I'm using the `igraph` package in R. I have a connected graph `G=(V,E)`, how can I randomly remove some edges (say, `n < |E|`) but without disconnecting the given graph. In other words, I mustn't remove any [bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29). Any hints on how that could be done?

Comment: This is not just about not removing bridges, because if you remove n edges, even if you don't remove any bridges, you might disconnect the graph.

Comment: Btw. I don't think there is a simple answer to this question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to keep randomly selecting and removing sets of `n` nodes until you found a set that doesn't increase the number of components of the graph:

```
remove.edges <- function(g, n) {
  num.tries <- 0
  while (TRUE) {
    num.tries <- num.tries + 1
    g2 <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[sample(seq_along(E(g)), n)])
    if (no.clusters(g2) == no.clusters(g)) {
      print(paste("Total number of tries:", num.tries))
      return(g2)
    }
  }
}
```

Let's try it out with a sample graph:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(144)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.4)
g2 <- remove.edges(g, 5)
# [1] "Total number of tries: 3"
```

This could be terribly inefficient for a large, sparse graph coupled with a large `n` value. In that case, you'll probably want to run something like [Tarjan's Bridge-Finding Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) at each iteration and limit your random selections to not be bridges. Unfortunately, I can't find an implementation of that algorithm in R, so you'd probably need to do some implementation to get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple technique is to find a cycle in the graph and remove an edge from this cycle.  To find a cycle I would do a depth first search until you find a node you have previously seen on the search.

For example, if you are at node `x` while performing the DFS and you discover a node `y` in `x`'s neighborhood, then if `x` also already exists in the DFS tree, you have found a cycle.  At this point you can safely remove any edge on this cycle without risk of it being a bridge.  This should run pretty quickly if the graph isn't very sparse.

Note that in practice this DFS technique will often just resemble a random walk around the graph until encountering a previously seen node.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants to remove n edges, not just one. And I guess he also wants to select the n edges uniformly in some sense.

Comment: He could do it `n` times :) It's guaranteed to finish in `O(En)` time for removing `n` edges from a graph with `E` edges.

Comment: Indeed. To select the edges uniformly is another question, though.